# Carrying out Excel Application actions on an Excel Worksheet object

Tags: c#, winforms, excel, vba

I have a C# application that is creating and working with an Excel spreadsheet. I worked on the spreadsheet independently and recorded a macro in order to see what the code generated looked like. Now of course this was generated in VB. In order to convert the code to C# I relied on the following [tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/09/28/converting-a-vba-macro-to-c-4-0.aspx). Now the problem is that in my application class I am manipulating an individual worksheet:

```
private Worksheet vstoSheet
```

which is being used elsewhere. This tutorial has enabled me to generate C# from the original VB code but carry out actions based on an Application object:

**Beginning of Macro code after conversion to C#:**

```
var excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
excelApp.Workbooks.Add();

excelApp.Rows["1:1"].Select();
excelApp.Selection.Insert(Shift: XlDirection.xlDown, CopyOrigin: XlInsertFormatOrigin.xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove);
excelApp.ActiveWindow.LargeScroll(ToRight: 1);
excelApp.Range["A1:L1"].Select();
```

My question is how can I relate all of this back to my Worksheet object? Currently I'm carrying out all of the actions on this new Application object but I need to carry them out on my Worksheet object. unfortunately methods like 'Selection' are not available on Worksheet objects. Is there some way I can carry out that I can convert one back to the other?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for but here is what I would do in VBA:

```
Range("A1").EntireRow.Insert
```

Just did some testing and this also works in VBA

```
Rows(1).Insert
```

So I would venture a guess that this would work.

```
excelApp.Range("A1").EntireRow.Insert
```

Many times you can combine your two lines of code that end in `.Select` and start with `Selection.`

Comment: I'm trying to get the carry out the same actions that I'm doing on the excelApp object above but instead on the vstoSheet object. In other words I want to carry out the methods of an Application object on a Worksheet object. The VB doesn't really come into it except that that is where the code came from originally.

Comment: My bad, I miss understood you question then.  I thought you said that Select and Selection were not working when you transferred it over to C# and that you needed a way to combine those methods.